# How to display images that in photo gallery that were just selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller, elcimagepickercontroller

**Goal:** The user selects photos from her photo gallery > Tap "Done" > Photos show up.

**Problem:** The photos don't show up immediately after "Done". They do show up if I open the picker again and tap "Cancel."

This worked fine (photo showed up instantly) when I was using UIImagePickerController, but then I switched to ELCImagePickerController for multiple selection and it no longer works.

**Hunches**

- CollectionView that displays all images is not being reloaded? But I tried calling `collectionView.reloadData()` after the images are selected (on the completionHandler). This did not work.

---

If helpful, this is my `elcImagePickerController` function from my `ViewController.swift`

```
func elcImagePickerController(picker: ELCImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [AnyObject]!) {

    println("inside elcImagePickerController")

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    if (info.count == 0) {
        return
    }

    var pickedImages = NSMutableArray()
    for any in info {
        let dict = any as! NSMutableDictionary
        let image = dict.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as! UIImage
        pickedImages.addObject(image)
    }

    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), {


        PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges(
            {

                for img in pickedImages{

                    // Request creating an asset from the image
                    // create multiple creationRequestForAssetFromImage

                    let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(img as! UIImage) // add to main gallery

                    // / Request editing the album
                    let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection, assets: self.photosAsset)

                    // Get a placeholder for the new asset and add it to the album editing request
                    let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset

                    albumChangeRequest.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])

                }


            }, completionHandler: {(success, error) in
                NSLog("Adding Image to Library -> %@", (success ? "Success" : "Error"))
                picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }
        )
    })
```

Comment: hey Aspen... i have used ELCImagePickerController to my app to select multiple images. In ELCImagePickerController selected images shown in Imageview in scrollview but i want to show those selected images in collection view instead of that scrollview in objective c. please give me code. I have try a lot of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to duplicate your scenario and error, but I managed and I found a solution!

You were on the right path with calling `collectionView.reloadData()` in the `completionHandler`, but it needed a bit more work.

---

1)

In my testing scenario, I've used a `PHFetchResult` called `photosAsset` as the main source for the `UICollectionView` (I'm presuming you have a similar setup).

You have to update this `PHFetchResult` to reflect the recent changes, in my case I used the following line:

```
self.photosAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(self.assetCollection, options: nil)
```

---

2)

It's correct that you have to reload the view with `collectionView.reloadData()`, but the code inside of the `completionHandler` is not run on the main thread/UI thread. So you have to call it like the following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.collectionView?.reloadData()})
```

---

Sum up:

In final, your `completionHandler` should look something similar to this:

```
completionHandler: {(success, error) in
    NSLog("Adding Image to Library -> %@", (success ? "Success" : "Error"))
    self.photosAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(self.assetCollection, options: nil)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.collectionView?.reloadData()})
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING. I HAVE SO MUCH LOVE FOR YOU RIGHT NOW.

Comment: hey Kumuluzz.. i have used ELCImagePickerController to my app to select multiple images. In ELCImagePickerController selected images shown in Imageview in scrollview but i want to show those selected images in collection view instead of that scrollview in objective c. please give me code. I have try a lot of.

Comment: Hi @bhavin. I'd love to help you out, but we should not do it here since this question is already finished and it would be off-topic. Instead you should create a new question, specific to your issue. You say that you have tried a lot, so remember to copy/paste that code into your question. Feel free to link me that new question here in the comments.